# What are the benefits of Spring Framework in Terms of Testing Application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, testing, spring-mvc

We have heard a lot about Benefits of Spring like it offers `loose coupling, dependency injection, inversion of control etc` but from `testing` point of view, I have couple of question.

- ***What are the advantages of Spring Framework in terms of testing an application?***
- ***Why Application developed using Spring as considered my testable as opposed to other Web Application?***

Please provide some useful examples as then it would be much more easier to understand explanation. I am new to Spring as such and want to understand precise benefits offered by `Spring Framework` from Application Developer point of view ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An application geared towards *dependency injection* is typically more testable because resources are easily replaced with test-oriented resources. Consider a service object that uses a data access object; in production, you'd inject a DAO that talked to a backend data store. But for *each* test you could create a DAO that returned specific, known data; this allows you to focus on the object being tested.

Spring is one of many dependency injection frameworks for Java, albeit the most popular; any DI framework is going to give you this kind of benefit.

Comment: In other words loose coupling helps Unit Testing because it makes easier to test a class independently from others, sometimes with the help of mock objects.

Comment: But let say my class is dependent on other classes then how can I test it more efficiently using Spring as opposed if I were not using Spring, in both the cases I have to create MockUp Objects then what difference would Spring bring?

Comment: Well, Spring can make injection of some objects automatic - for example, you could load a full configuration context, and then replace parts of it as you needed (assuming you were using mutators and not constructors for injection.) 

Spring has good tooling and diagnostics for those purposes; as far as "is Spring *soooooooo* compelling for testing" is concerned, I don't know - I find the mentality behind loose coupling far more useful than a framework that leverages it.

Comment: I was waiting for someone else to comment, since I'm not the most qualified to do it, but since there are no further comments I'll try. My understanding is that if you code with dependency injection, and you code to interfaces and not to concrete classes, with or without Spring, it will be easier to test. The problem of not using Spring or another DI framework, is, that I believe you'll have to call your DI Object setters from other code introducing tight coupling anyway. I'll be happy to be integrated or corrected, we are here to learn :-)